# SBT resolver for oss.sonatype.org not working

Tags: java, scala, maven, build, sbt

I have a problem (likely related to a bad configuration of my build.sbt file) but for the last 15 minutes I've been unable to figure out what.

I have the following build.sbt:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

version := "0.1"

resolvers +=
  "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"

libraryDependencies += "io.plasmap" %% "geow" % "0.3.11-SNAPSHOT"
```

For some reason when I try to run `sbt update` (or compile or run) I get an error along the lines of:

> sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency:
>   io.plasmap#geow_2.12;0.3.11-SNAPSHOT: not found

Which is strange, because the snapshot I'm trying to download is most definitely in that repo. So what exactly am I doing wrong ? How instead should I be configuring my build file ? The sbt page on resolvers is not helping http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Resolvers.html :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%%` tells `sbt` that it should append the current version of Scala being used to the artifacts and then download that one, so it's basically looking to download `geow_2.12` which hasn't been published as you can see from [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/io/plasmap/).

You can explicitly specify which one to download by changing it to:

`"io.plasmap" % "geow_2.11" % "0.3.11-SNAPSHOT"`

Note that it may be binary incompatible with Scala 2.12, so you may need to change your `scalaVersion` to 2.11.8 in order to use that library (at which point you can obviously go back to using `%%` notation). This concept of building a library for multiple Scala versions is called cross-building and you can read more about it [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Cross-Build.html).

Comment: It is overwhelmingly likely to be binary incompatible with Scala 2.12. Using a library with a mismatched Scala version basically isn't even worth trying.

Comment: @SethTisue Yes, that's what I assumed based on the release notes for Scala 2.12. Thanks for the clarification.