# Adding Spark "Library" to a Scala project

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I'm going through a book and the author left out the part of actually providing the project with the Scala libraries for Spark. So things like

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
```

Are not working (failing on the apache).

I'm new to Scala (and JVM languages in general) and am not even sure what to search for. Should I be looking for jars? How would I add them? I'm using intelliJ if that helps with the explanation.

I do have spark running so i think it is the the "client" spark library for scala that I need to install.

So using the answer below I'm much closer now (using sbt now) but I have the following error:

[image]

build.sbt is now:

```
name := "gettingThingsRunning"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.5.1" )
```

Comment: Please consider reading the Spark quick start page: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications

Comment: The best way to import external libraries is to use a build tool like `[sbt] (http://www.scala-sbt.org/)`. The you will have access to the libraries when you build. However to actually run your built project you will also need a spark environment configured

Comment: @Bren If you've created the SBT project, can you show your build.sbt?

Comment: @YoungSpice just added. I suspect version clashes.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a dependency manager like Maven or sbt.

With sbt, you can add a `build.sbt` file in your project root folder with something like:

```
name := "Simple Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.2"
```

Then you can use IntelliJ's Scala plug-in to "refresh" your project and re-index the dependencies.

**Edit:**
Assuming you created your project using the SBT option, you can use the SBT functionality found in the sidebar for refreshing your dependencies:

[image]

[image]

Regarding Spark, I recommend reading the [Spark quick start page](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications), particularly the section called "Self-contained applications".

For IntelliJ and SBT projects, I believe you would profit from reading the following page:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/getting-started-with-sbt.html

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the "refresh" step? And thanks for the link that was useful.

Comment: @Bren, have you created the project as an SBT project in IntelliJ?

Comment: no, just remade it as such. Thanks trying figure out where everything goes.

Comment: @Bren, I added some more information and some links to some reference. I hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, I think I'm getting closer though I have a error as shown above.

Comment: @Bren, for spark 1.5.1, you need to use Scala version 2.10.X. I think 2.10.4 should work. For spark 2.0.2 you can use Scala up to 2.11.8.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `scalaVersion` to `2.11.8`. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086160/sbt-resolver-for-oss-sonatype-org-not-working/) for details.